# Steps for upgrading to Cisco DNA Center?

Tags: cisco-ios, sdn, prime

Has Anyone upgraded from **cisco Prime** to **Cisco DNAC**, if so then Does anyone have Steps (Prep Work) checklist suggestions before beginning the Brownfield Deployment of **Cisco DNAC** ?

Comment: See https://gblogs.cisco.com/ca/2020/07/15/demystifying-prime-infrastructure-to-cisco-dna-center-migration/ and https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/prime/infrastructure/3-9/migration/guide/bk_Cisco_Prime_Infrastructure_to_DNAC_Co-existence_guide.html

Comment: Thank you for the Suggestion, the following links helped. @hertitu

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisco publishes a [Cisco Prime Infrastructure to Cisco Digital Network Architecture Center Prime Data Migration Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/prime/infrastructure/3-9/migration/guide/bk_Cisco_Prime_Infrastructure_to_DNAC_Co-existence_guide.html).

The guide states:

> You can migrate devices, location groups, associated site maps, user
> defined CLI templates and CMX data from Cisco Prime Infrastructure to
> Cisco DNA Center and manage your enterprise network over a centralized
> dashboard.

Consult the [Compatibility Matrix](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/prime/infrastructure/3-9/migration/guide/bk_Cisco_Prime_Infrastructure_to_DNAC_Co-existence_guide/m_introduction.html#ariaid-title3) as a first step.

Answer (score 0):

Prime and Cisco DNAC are two different products, there is no upgrade process . Basically you migrate from Prime to Cisco DNAC.
Till now as DNAC is still a new product, its advised to use DNAC for assurance only and use prime for configuration for a brownfield deployment.

Comment: I appreciate your response, Any Idea on how that migration process will take place, If i were to migrate from cisco Prime to Cisco DNAC ?